# Collision of two objects

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, sknode

I want to know if there is a way to check the perfect collision of two `SpriteKitNode` objects. Below I added an example of what I want.[image]

I tried the `SKNode.intersects(_:)` but this check the collision of the whole object yellow and pink rather than the object from images.

The objects I will use will be a `SKSpriteKitNode` with a png `SKTexture`.

Thanks!

Comment: There are lots if ways.  Search pixel perfect collision and you will find an answer to meet your needs.  Give them an upvote when you do.

Comment: What he said, but also bear in mind that we all ideally *want* pixel-perfect collisions in our game but they are computationally expensive and generally not required - the default solution of using a bounding box//circle/polygon (which is not the same as using the sprite's frame as in your example) is usually good enough and indistinguishable from perfect collisions.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, but an attempt to illustrate my comment above. Physics bodies used for collision detection can be (in increasing order of computational cost) circles, rectangles, polygons or bitmap perfect.

Unless you have a very-real need for pixel-perfect collisions (large sprites, slow-moving etc), using circular and rectangular physics bodies for your scenario (the red outlines in the 'wrong' section' of the image below) might be enough:

[image]

The axe body could be easily change if necessary to an 'L' shaped polygon, for more accurate collisions with a (hopefully) slight increase in cost.

Comment: Making it 2 box nodes would be more efficient than an L shaped polygon

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Doh! - didn't think of that! Explanation for the OP - you can create an array of PBs (physics bodies) and use that array to create a new PB.

Comment: It has to be 2 nodes,  an array of Pb just merges line points.

Comment: So is that 2 PBs with a joint?

Comment: No need for a joint, just make the head and body two separate nodes, and constrain them somehow